# How To Handle File Input

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, web

I am working on a tutorial website using MERN, whereon I will be displaying tutorials on pretty much anything I know well, and new things that I learn. The backend and frontend work fine. I just don't know what to do with regards to the tutorial's body in the submission form. The kind of tutorials that I want to add will have a combination of images, specially highlighted text(i.e. code examples), and text. So, I was thinking maybe I can upload all that as a word document and have it be parsed before it is saved in the database. Is this the way to go? Are there useful libraries that can make this easier to handle?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you'll like [markdown](https://www.markdownguide.org).
Markdown is a simple markup language where you enter plain old text but can render the text with styles. There are many libraries (especially for react and node) that will convert your markdown to html, and it can be easily extended to style code snippets, images, and even react components.

Comment: Thank you for bringing that up. I kid you not, I was just looking at markdown before I changed tabs to check in on stackoverflow and saw your comment. I'll do more research on it.